# Json_encode в PHP?

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$arr = array('acceptMessageFrom' => array('0', '2'));
```

К которому применен:

```
json_encode($arr);
```

**Результат:**

```
{"acceptMessageFrom":["0","2"]}
```

Когда делаю `json_decode($arr);`

Получаю:

```
object(stdClass)#236 (1) {   ["acceptMessageFrom"]=>   array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "2"   } }
```

Почему в обратном направлении не получаю исходный массив, а объект?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Внимательно читайте документацию!

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )

Принимает закодированную в JSON строку и преобразует ее в переменную PHP.

Список параметров 
assoc - Если TRUE, возвращаемые объекты будут преобразованы в ассоциативные массивы.
```

---

```
$arr = array('acceptMessageFrom' => array('0', '2'));
$a = json_encode($arr);
var_dump(json_decode($a, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Почему в обратном направлении не получаю исходный массив, а объект?

Потому, что в JavaScript отсутствует такой тип данных как ассоциативный массив – вместо него там объекты. Ассоциативный массив при преобразовании в JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) становится объектом. И при обратном преобразовании из объекта получается объект.

Однако, у php'шного [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php) есть опция (второй аргумент), включение которой сделает из объектов ассоциативный массив:

```
print_r( json_decode( '{"acceptMessageFrom":["0","2"]}', TRUE));

/* Результат:
Array(
    [acceptMessageFrom] => Array(
        [0] => 0
        [1] => 2
    )
)
*/
```